# Keep getting 'You have requested a non-existent service "test.client"' in Symfony2 Beta3

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to setup a unit test but whenever I run "phpunit -c app" I get this error:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "test.client".

The code in my test case is just:

```
public function testNonAuthenticatedPathsIndex()
{
    $client = $this->createClient();
}
```

If I don't make the call to createClient everything runs correctly. I've checked AppKernel.php to make sure the FrameworkBundle (I believe that's where this service is defined) is definitely still in there and it is.

I'm a bit confused as to what might be causing this as I've managed to do this kind of thing before.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Have you enabled the `framework.test` option in <kbd>config_test.yml</kbd>?

```
framework:
  test: ~
```

Comment: That's fixed it. Annoyed I didn't spot that myself so thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 thanks, where is this in the docs?  I must have missed it.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2014 with Symfony 2.3.22. Thanks!

Comment: @wesside : it's displayed on [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#test) but not in the linked page.

Comment: Still valid with symfony 2.7

Comment: Still valid with symfony 2.8.2!

Comment: Still valid with Symfony 3.0.6

Comment: `framework.test` is set by default in 3.4 but error is still there

Answer (score 10):

In `phpunit.xml` you should have env variable like:

```
<env name="APP_ENV" value="test"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with symfony version 3.3.13.

The `config_test.yml` file was fine, but I did the same mistake.

I solved adding the `<server name ="APP_ENV" value="test" />` option under `php` in the phpunit.xml file

Comment: This does not fix it in my 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

[composer require symfony/browser-kit](https://github.com/FriendsOfBehat/SymfonyExtension/issues/88#issuecomment-562514975)

The definition `test.client` depends upon `AbstractBrowser::class` presence

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with remote builds of my project. This issue was connected with empty `symfony.lock` file in the root of my project. This file is for preventing symfony recipes execution twice. But my `symfony.lock` was corrupted and empty so framework-bundle executed it's recipe and replaced my `APP_ENV` variable in `phpunit.xml.dist` from `test` to `dev`. The reason why it happened was `repositories` node in `composer.json` (https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/347)

I'm fixing this situation by adding dependencies in `symfony.lock` by my hands